# VBA Macro for Thick Borders on cells (After evaluating if cells in range are >0, need offset)

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code is not running ,  It is stuck on ActiveCell.Offset.

```
Sub Borders()
For Each cell In Range("BO5:CL120")

    If cell.Value > 0 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -54).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.BorderAround _
            ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThick
        Exit For
    End If

Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: No Conditional Formatting is possible for thick black borders

Comment: Wrong use of `ActiveCell`

Comment: So how you fix it

Comment: replace everything inside the if with `cell.Offset(0, -54).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThick`

Comment: It did it in just one cell

Comment: I would just use a different approach see [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find). If you want to understand what's wrong with that line then suggest reading these pages: 
[Application.ActiveCell property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell), [Range.Offset property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset), [Range.Range property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range)

Comment: It did one cell becuase you are exiting the loop.  Remove the `Exit For`

Answer (score 0):

This uses array to limit as much as possible the interaction between the code and sheet.

```
Sub Borders()

    Dim rngarray As Variant
    rngarray = ActiveSheet.Range("BO5:CL120").Value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(rngarray, 1) To UBound(rngarray, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(rngarray, 2) To UBound(rngarray, 2)
            If rngarray(i, j) > 0 Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("L4").Offset(i, j).BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlThick
            End If
        Next j
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the help. The Macro does not like this part "  If rngarray(i, j) > 0 Then"

Comment: Then your data range has  errors in it.  You cannot compare an error.  you will need to add an If to test for errors and ignore it.

Answer (score -2):

Turn on the Macro Recorder and click through the steps to do what you need to do.  When done, copy/paste the results code into the small script you have now.  The Recorder will give you everything you need, but you will have more than you actually need, so do a bit of editing and you're done.